# Impossible to add opaque action in activity diagram

Tags: uml, uml-designer

The activity diagram creation have some weird behaviour when used with partitions : it was impossible for me to add any "opaque action" in the partitions. After a while and some researches into the documentation it seems that there is no particular things to do for that. The only workaround I've found is to put an opaque action *outside* the partition which is allowed and then *move* it to the partition as shown in the picture.

I'm sure I do something wrong here but what? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to select an opaque action from the palette and then click in a partition, the opaque action appears directly in the partition.
Which version of UML Designer do you use? It seems to work correctly for me with the 7.1.

Comment: I'm using the 8.0.0.201703170943

Comment: This is a beta version of the 8.0.0 which will be released in July. It seems that there is a regression, thanks for your feedback we will fix it soon.

Comment: ok : ACtually I have to get back to a stable version. BTW: it seems that other regressions are presents. Anyway, this soft. worth the try. Continuez les gars.

Comment: If you detect other problems as beta tester do not hesitate to report bugs, we really appreciate!